# Where is the constructor in this class?

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class EqualsTest {
  public static <T> boolean equalTest(T o1, T o2) {
      return o1.equals(o2);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      EqualsTest et1 = new EqualsTest();
      EqualsTest et2 = new EqualsTest();
      System.out.println(et1.equals(et2));
      System.out.println(equalTest(et1, et2));
  }
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (o instanceof EqualsTest) {
          System.out.println("equals(Object)");
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
  public boolean equals(EqualsTest et) {
      System.out.println("equals(EqualsTest)");
      return this.equals((Object)et);
  }
}
```

Comment: The answer to this question could have been found by simply googling "java constructor"

Comment: @Azzi: Googling *"java constructor"* won't explain to you the concept of having an implicit default constructor in this particular class...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is none, it is implicit.  Since it does not explicitly `extends` any class, it will implicitly extend `Object`.  And since Object has a no-arg constructor, it will implicitly call up to that one.

Really, the class could contain a constructor written as this, and it would be equivalent:

```
public class EqualsTest {
    public EqualsTest() {
        super();
    }

    //the methods...
}
```

You cannot use implicit constructors if the class you extend does not also have a 'no-arg' constructor (whether implicit or explicit).  If you provide **any** explicit constructor, there will be no implicit no-arg constructor created for you.

Comment: what happens if they're implicit?

Answer (score 2):

There is no constructor defined in the class so Java will add a Default Constructor on compilation . 
Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor#Java_and_C.23

Answer (score 2):

**There is no explicit constructor in your class.** You are using the `implicit` constructor from `Object` class in the statements as below:

```
  EqualsTest et1 = new EqualsTest();
```

For your understanding, constructor are normally defined as below:

```
  public EqualsTest(){ //without param
  }


  public EqualsTest(int param1){ //with one param
  }
```

**Please note:** The primary differentiation in the constructor and other methods is: **Constructor has same name as your class and doesn't have any return type.**

Answer (score 2):

All java classes without an explicitly declared constructor get a default no-arg constructor of the form

```
public ClassName()
{
  super();
}
```

Inside the implicit constructor is a call to the constructor of the superclass of your class (Object by default), hence the 'super();'

Comment: The implicit constructor makes one call: super()

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify any constructor, one it is provided. If you provide one, you have to override the one which is by default. So here you have provided constructor.

Answer (score 2):

If a class does not have any constructors it creates an implicit one, in your case

```
public EqualsTest(){}
```

will be there. If you create a constructor which takes any parameters you will lose this implicit constructor, and if you want a no argument constructor you will have to construct it.

Comment: The implicit constructor makes one call: super()

Answer (score 2):

The `main` method is the entry point to your application. It is invoked when you start it up and there is no instantiation here. You can create a constructor if you want:

```
public class Main {
    /**
     * Main.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        // do something more
    }

    public Main() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

and you can even instantiate `Main` as you can see in my code. In this case you can create a constructor for `Main` otherwise `Object`'s default constructor will be called.

You can even do this it makes sense to you:

```
public class Main {
    /**
     * Main.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main("some param");
    }

    public Main() {
        // do something
    }

    public Main(String someParameter) {
        this();
    }

}
```

but keep in mind that without your intervention your `Main` class won't get instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

If not specified, the constructor is implicit.

That means you can instantiate that class by calling `new EqualsTest()`.

When instead you define a constructor with arguments, you lose this feature, and you are forced to write the code for the default, no-arg constructor too, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

If no constructor is specified there is an implicit constructor. In your case

```
 public EqualsTest(){
     super();
 }
```

If you declare a constructor this implicit one is not present any more and you would have to explicitly declare a no args constructor

Answer (score 2):

Java provides a default constructor which takes no arguments and performs no special actions or initializations, when no explicit constructors are provided.

The only action taken by the implicit default constructor is to call the superclass constructor using the super() call.

Answer (score 2):

An implicit constructor is there in your case which is calling the object class constructor

implicit constructo
look like

```
public  EqualsTest()
{
 super();
}
```